# Simple way to make test file in bash

Tags: bash

Working with file reading instruments I regularly need some text file to test a code. I would like to make such file quickly. I guess it would be great to produce the file with some bash one-liner. What is the simpler way to make file that contains text like:

```
r
rr
rrr
rrrr
rrrrr
rrrrrr
rrrrrrr
rrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrr
...
```

Comment: `vi file` is one line and is pretty simple. What makes your test file harder? (More lines?) printf would work, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
file=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXX) && echo -e "r\nrr\nrrr\nrrrr\nrrrrr\nrrrrrr\nrrrrrrr\nrrrrrrrr\nrrrrrrrrr" > $file.
```

`mktemp /tmp/XXXXXX` will create a file with a random name. Each 'X' will be replaced with a random character. You can replace '/tmp' with any other location you have access to.

Answer (score 1):

`R='' && for ((i=1;i<=$WHATEVER_YOU_WANT;i++)); do R="${R}r" && echo $R >> testfile; done`

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* way is to run

```
cat > file
```

Then, select the text from your question, middle click to paste it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you mean that you want a command that creates a file with increasing repetitions of a character on each line, you could try:

```
$ perl -le 'for $i (1..10){print $ARGV[0] x $i}' "r"
r
rr
rrr
rrrr
rrrrr
rrrrrr
rrrrrrr
rrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrr
rrrrrrrrrr
```

To print another string, change the `"r"` to whatever you want. For more repetitions, change the `(1..10)` to `(1..N)` where `N` is the maximum repetitions.

Finally, to save to a file, just redirect:

```
perl -le 'for $i (1..10){print $ARGV[0] x $i}' "r" > file
```